# TYPO3: Custom options for "insert plugin" in backend

Tags: typo3, backend

I am learning TYPO3 and extensions, for now, I've created a test extension about image uploading, handling and showing.

I have done the Backend for upload a new image, show a list, and edit image properties (once selected). This part is already implemented and working.

Now I am missing the "include" part, I mean, to insert an image in page via Insert Plugin on BackEnd.

My problem: When I select insert plugin, and I manually select my registered plugin, I want to render there a fluid template with options, image list, and so.
These options are for the user to select an image, a size, and so, for it to be shown in selected page.

I don't know which method have typo3 for showing templates in that part, so I am requesting a hint from where to config a template to be used there by TYPO3.

Note: This is not about asking implementations, just a hint to start and implement it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not code that on your own.

I guess you are looking for [TCA](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.7.1/view/1/2/). In special for your Plugin you are looking for "[flexforms](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.7.1/view/1/3/#id588476)". I guess this [wiki page](http://wiki.typo3.org/Extension_Development,_using_Flexforms) can help you get started with some examples.

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit confused of the TYPO3 terms. I'll try that and accept response according after that. I thought I could add some fluid template and load there somehow.

Comment: Well, i guess it would be possible. But you should not:) The backend is a generic form-builder. There a lot of built in functions you do not need to care about. Think about rights management, Caching, Translation Management, Workspaces etc.. There are standard components you should be fine with. If not, there are "user" fields in TCA as well. But usually you will not need them.

Comment: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tca/4.7.1/view/1/3/ => ['columns'][field name]['config'] / TYPE: "user" 
But just do not use it - until it is proven that you need.

Comment: I have tested flexforms and I do have now an empty template. Just missing an implementation. Many thanks, as learning typo3 can be a very hard task in some matters :)